# Http getter function is not accepting params

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, filesaver.js

I'm trying to download a file using filesaver in Angular. While I'm able to add params to my HttpCient getter function, the minute I switch to a custom http module, which I wrote so I can include authorization headers, it simply ignores the params I'm trying to add. I tried changing my getter function based on a HttpClient getter function, but nothing seems to work. FYI the http module works well for all my other services. Any ideas?

my http custom module:

```
  get<T>(url:string, options) {
    const httpOptions  = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': sgwtConnect.getAuthorizationHeader(),
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }),
      params: options
    }
    return this.http.get(url, httpOptions).toPromise();
  }
```

my download file service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
// import {HttpWithHeadersModule} from "./httpWithHeaders/http-with-headers.module";
import {AppConfig} from "../app.config";
import {ReportBatches} from "../models/reportBatches";
import {HttpParams, HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {HttpWithHeadersModule} from "./httpWithHeaders/http-with-headers.module";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DownloadFileService {
  private apiUrl = '';
  private downloadFilesEndPoint;
  // private pathToDownload = String;

  constructor(private http: HttpWithHeadersModule, private appConfig: AppConfig) {
    this.apiUrl = this.appConfig.settings.apiServer.apiUrl;
    this.downloadFilesEndPoint = this.appConfig.settings.apiServer.downloadFileEndPoint;
  }

downloadFile(data) {
    const REQUEST_PARAMS = new HttpParams().set('pathToDownload', data.pathToDownload);
    const REQUEST_URI = this.downloadFilesEndPoint;
    return this.http.get(REQUEST_URI,
             REQUEST_PARAMS
            //responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    )
  }
}
```

my ts componenet

```
import {animate, state, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator} from "@angular/material/paginator";
import {MatSort} from "@angular/material/sort";
import {from} from 'rxjs';
import {ReportService} from 'src/app/services/report.service';
import {DownloadFileService} from "../../../services/download-file.service";
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';
import {ReportBatches} from "../../../models/reportBatches";
import {MatTableDataSource} from "@angular/material/table";
import {saveAs} from 'file-saver';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-report',
  styleUrls: ['./report.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './report.component.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('void', style({height: '0px', minHeight: '0', visibility: 'hidden'})),
      state('*', style({height: '*', visibility: 'visible'})),
      transition('void <=> *', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)'))
    ])
  ],
})
export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {
  reportBatches: ReportBatches[];
  dateValue = new Date();
  maxDate = new Date();
  currentDate = new Date();
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<ReportBatches>;
  expandedElement: ReportBatches | null;

  displayedReportsColumn: string[] = ['transferStatus', 'fisReportName', 'lastModified', 'numberOfRecords', 'addArrow'];

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  isExpansionDetailRow = (index, row) => row.hasOwnProperty('detailRow');

  constructor(private reportService: ReportService, private downloadFileService: DownloadFileService, private datePipe: DatePipe) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.callReportService(new Date());
  }

  reportDateChange(value: Date) {

    const currentValue = this.datePipe.transform(this.dateValue, 'yyyyMMdd');
    const newSelectedValue = this.datePipe.transform(value, 'yyyyMMdd');
    if (currentValue !== newSelectedValue) {
      this.callReportService(value);
      this.dateValue = value;
    }
  }

  callReportService(value: Date) {
    from(this.reportService.getReportsAndBatches(value))
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.reportBatches = <ReportBatches[]>res;
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(this.reportBatches));
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.reportBatches);
        // this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      });
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // Datasource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

  refreshDate() {
    this.callReportService(this.dateValue);
  }

  downloadFile(pathToDownload) {
    console.log(pathToDownload);
    from(this.downloadFileService.downloadFile({'pathToDownload': pathToDownload}))
  .subscribe((data:any)  => {
    saveAs(new Blob([data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'}), pathToDownload);
    })
  }


}
```

my html file

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form>
      <label for="reportDate" class="col-form-label">Enter Creation Date:</label>
      <div class="input1">
        <input id="reportDate"
               class="form-control"
               #dp="bsDatepicker"
               (bsValueChange)="reportDateChange($event)"
               [maxDate]="maxDate"
               bsDatepicker
               [bsValue]="dateValue"
               [bsConfig]="{ isAnimated: true, adaptivePosition: true, dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD', containerClass: 'theme-red'}"/>
      </div>
      <div class="input1">
        <mat-form-field color="warn" appearance="legacy">
          <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <!--    <div class="input1">Last Refreshed at: {{currentDate | date :'mediumTime'}}</div>-->
      <div class="input1">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" (click)="refreshDate()">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>Refresh
        </button>
      </div>
</form>
<div class="report-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="transferStatus">
      <mat-header-cell class=col1 *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Transfer Status</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell class=col1 *matCellDef="let report">{{report.transferStatus}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="fisReportName">
      <mat-header-cell class=col2 *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>FIS Report Name</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell class=col2 *matCellDef="let report">{{report.remoteFileNameOnFTA}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="lastModified">
      <mat-header-cell class=col3 *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Last Modified</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell class=col3 *matCellDef="let report">{{report.lastModified | date :'medium'}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="numberOfRecords">
      <mat-header-cell class=col4 *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Number Of Records</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell class=col4 *matCellDef="let report">{{report.numberOfRecords}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container class=col5 matColumnDef="addArrow">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let report">
        <mat-icon (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === report ? null : report">expand_more</mat-icon>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #tpl let-report>
      <div class="mat-row detail-row" [@detailExpand] style="overflow: hidden">
        <mat-list>
          <mat-list-item><b class="title">File Size: </b>{{report.contentLength}}</mat-list-item>
          <mat-list-item><b class="title">Creation Date:</b> {{report.creationDate | date}}</mat-list-item>
          <mat-list-item><b class="title">Azure File Name:</b> {{report.adlsFullPath}}</mat-list-item>
          <!--          .substring(report.adlsFullPath.indexOf('part'))}}-->
          <mat-list-item><b class="title">Data Path:</b> {{report.dataPath}}</mat-list-item>
          <mat-list-item><b class="title">Batch Version:</b> {{report.version}}</mat-list-item>
          <mat-list-item><b class="title">Batch Source:</b> {{report.source}}</mat-list-item>
                    <mat-list-item><b class="title"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" (click)="downloadFile(report.adlsFullPath)">Download File</button></b></mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedReportsColumn"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedReportsColumn;" matRipple
             class="element-row" [cdkDetailRow]="row"
             [cdkDetailRowTpl]="tpl">
    </mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works, and so does my getter function. but it doesn't let me add params. I'm using IntelliJ and I get no errors, but it simply ignores my params. that doesn't happen when I use HttpClient, but then I have an issue that I don't have my authorization headers that I need.

Comment: Why can't you add your headers to the HttpClient get method? If you want to avoid doing that for every request, use an http interceptor to attach your headers to all outgoing requests

Comment: I added the headers and I've updated my code accordingly. I have no errors now from the get function, but it again ignores my params. I'm  trying to find the correct syntax that would tell my get function to accepts parameters. right now they're just being ignored

Comment: I made some adjustment to the get option and the dowloadFile function in the service and it's working now. I'm updating the code.

Comment: the function now works, but my http getter function will now only work if I specify httpOptions. The trouble is that this interferes with other functions where I don't specify the params and the responseType. Even if I try to define them,  they still give me an error. My error saysERROR in src/app/routes/report/report/report.component.ts(60,30): error TS2352: Conversion of type 'ArrayBuffer' to type 'ReportBatches[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the ot
her. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first. I'm updating the code

Comment: @HeidiEigner If you have solved your problem then you should post the answer in the answers section, not as an edition of your question.

Answer (score 0):

my mistake was that I forgot to add api_url, so the getter was calling localhost instead of my api. This is the corrected code for the download function in my download service:

```
downloadFile(data) {
    const REQUEST_PARAMS = new HttpParams().set('pathToDownload', data.pathToDownload);
    const REQUEST_URI = this.apiUrl + this.downloadFilesEndPoint;
    // console.log('uri is: ', REQUEST_URI);
    return this.http.get(REQUEST_URI, {
      params: REQUEST_PARAMS,
      responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    })
  }
```